# Table Convert To Text method C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, rtf

I have a `RichTextBox` in Rtf format. The user can currently paste in tables. I want to take this functionality away *i.e strip the tables from the Rtf on paste*.

I need to keep the `RichTextBox` in Rtf as I need to keep bullets, numbered lists etc. so can't simply paste in plain text.

I'm currently locking down the formatting of pasted text like this which works well but can't find any methods to remove tables...

```
     private void _btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, "12");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, "Arial");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, "Normal");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null);                      
     }
```

Iterating over the Rtf & removing the tags looks very complex as each paste will be different. I noticed in Word there's Table `ConvertToText` functionality which does exactly what I need.

Does anyone know if there's a method in .NET which can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm beginning to believe that there is no solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone is trying to achieve this I don't think it's possible. Maybe you can iterate over a simple table in an Rtf string and remove the tags but if you can't determine user input the Rtf is by far too complex. Therefore here's my solution (of sorts...)

```
        private void _btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {              
           TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);

          rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Table.BorderThicknessProperty, "3");
          rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Table.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);
         }
```

In the 'Format' button click event I've set table borders to Red. On my save back to the database method I've used this simple `if` statement:

```
    private void SaveToDbCommandAction()
    {
        if(PastedText.Contains("trowd"))
        {
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Cannot save Article. Please remove pasted tables");          
        }
        else
        {
            SaveToDb(RTBText);
        }            
    }
```

Therefore when the user pastes in a table they are warned via the red cell borders. This is particularly useful if they paste a table with invisible borders and can't actually see the table. The If statement then determines whether the Rtf string contains a 'trowd' tag therefore preventing the save.